# How to use b2Draw with SDL2? DrawSegment is not called

Tags: c++, box2d, sdl-2

I expect to see `hello` in the console:

DebugDrawer.cpp

```
#include "DebugDrawer.h"
#include <iostream>

DebugDrawer::DebugDrawer()
{

}

void DebugDrawer::DrawSegment(const b2Vec2 &p1, const b2Vec2 &p2, const b2Color &color)
{
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}

void DebugDrawer::DrawSolidPolygon(const b2Vec2 *vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color &color) { }
void DebugDrawer::DrawPolygon(const b2Vec2 *vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color &color) { }
void DebugDrawer::DrawPoint(const b2Vec2 &p, float size, const b2Color &color) { }
void DebugDrawer::DrawCircle(const b2Vec2 &center, float radius, const b2Color &color) { }
void DebugDrawer::DrawSolidCircle(const b2Vec2 &center, float radius, const b2Vec2 &axis, const b2Color &color) { }
void DebugDrawer::DrawTransform(const b2Transform &xf) { }
```

I inherited from the `b2Draw` and overloaded the methods:

DebugDrawer.h

```
#ifndef DEBUGDRAWER_H
#define DEBUGDRAWER_H

#include "box2d/b2_draw.h"

class DebugDrawer : public b2Draw
{
public:
    DebugDrawer();

private:
    void DrawSolidPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawPoint (const b2Vec2 &p, float size, const b2Color &color);
    void DrawPolygon(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 vertexCount, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float radius, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawSolidCircle(const b2Vec2& center, float radius, const b2Vec2& axis, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawSegment(const b2Vec2& p1, const b2Vec2& p2, const b2Color& color);
    void DrawTransform(const b2Transform& xf);
};

#endif // DEBUGDRAWER_H
```

I created an object with the box shape:

```
    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(50.f / WORLD_SCALE, 50.f / WORLD_SCALE);

    b2BodyDef bdef;
    bdef.type = b2_staticBody;

    pBody = pWorld->CreateBody(&bdef);
    pBody->CreateFixture(&shape, 2.f);
```

I set the debug draw in the `main.cpp` file:

```
    pDebugDrawer = new DebugDrawer();
    pWorld->SetDebugDraw(pDebugDrawer);
```

I set flags:

```
   uint32 flags = 0;
    flags += b2Draw::e_shapeBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_jointBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_centerOfMassBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_aabbBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_pairBit;
    pDebugDrawer->SetFlags(flags);
```

I call `pWorld.Step()` and `pWorld->DebugDraw()`:

```
        pWorld->Step(0.016f, 8, 3);
        pWorld->DebugDraw();
```

main.cpp

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 0x00000001;
#endif

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <box2d/box2d.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "DebugDrawer.h"

const float WORLD_SCALE = 30.f;
b2World* pWorld;
DebugDrawer* pDebugDrawer;
b2Body* pBody;

int main()
{
    // Initialize the SDL2 library
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        SDL_Log("Failed to initialize the SDL2 library: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SDL window
    const int WIN_WIDTH = 500;
    const int WIN_HEIGHT = 500;
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Empty Window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    // Create a SDL renderer
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
        window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (!renderer)
    {
        SDL_Log("Failed to create a SDL renderer %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    // Initialize the GLAD library
    if (!gladLoadGL())
    {
        SDL_Log("Failed to initialize the GLAD library");
        return 1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

    b2Vec2 gravity(0.f, 9.8f);
    pWorld = new b2World(gravity);

    pDebugDrawer = new DebugDrawer();
    pWorld->SetDebugDraw(pDebugDrawer);

    uint32 flags = 0;
    flags += b2Draw::e_shapeBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_jointBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_centerOfMassBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_aabbBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_pairBit;
    pDebugDrawer->SetFlags(flags);

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(50.f / WORLD_SCALE, 50.f / WORLD_SCALE);

    b2BodyDef bdef;
    bdef.type = b2_staticBody;

    pBody = pWorld->CreateBody(&bdef);
    pBody->CreateFixture(&shape, 2.f);

    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);

    while (running)
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = false;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                running = false;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        pWorld->Step(0.016f, 8, 3);
        pWorld->DebugDraw();

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    }

    delete pWorld;
    delete pDebugDrawer;

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think box2d should call `DrawSegment` and not e.g. `DrawPolygon` in your case?

Comment: @keltar I thought everything must work because I set all frags to true. Yes, `DrawPolygon` works, thanks! But why `DrawSegment` does not work?

Comment: Temporary I can get segments from polygon.

Comment: Flags control what to draw, not how to draw it. E.g. AABB is a rectangle, which could be drawn as a single polygon or four lines - and box2d uses first option. I suppose you're expected to implement all drawing functions to have proper results.

Comment: @keltar You are right! I tried to create an instance of `b2EdgeShape` and `DrawSegment` was called. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use `DrawPolygon` to draw segments of colliders when I use boxes to draw borders around game objects. `DrawSegment()` will be called when an instance of `b2EdgeShape` is created:

```cpp
    b2EdgeShape edgeShape;
    edgeShape.SetOneSided(b2Vec2(0.f, 0.f), b2Vec2(1.f, 0.f),
                          b2Vec2(2.f, 0.f), b2Vec2(3.f, 0.f));
    m_pEdgeBody = m_pWorld->CreateBody(&bdef);
    m_pEdgeBody->CreateFixture(&edgeShape, 2.f);
```